# EF Core 3.1.7 Data annotations for multiple 1:1 relationships in table

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am having problems figuring out the data annotations to map more than one 1:1 relationships so that EF Core 3.11.7 understands it and can build a migration.

I have a Person table and a Notes table.
There is a 0:M Notes relationship in Person. A person record can have 0 or more notes.

In the notes table is a CreatedBy field which is a Person. It also has a LastEditedBy field which is also a person. EF keeps bombing on how to construct the relationship for Note.CreatedBy. If this were non EF, both fields would be ints with the PersonID of the proper person record. How do it, preferabbly with Data Annotations, explain this to EF Core?

When I try to create a migration it fails and says:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Note.CreatedBy' of type 'Person'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VetReg.Domain.Model
{
    public class Family
    {
        public int FamilyID { get; set; } = -1;
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; } = new List<Pet>();
        public List<PersonFamily> People { get; set; }
        public int AddressID { get; set; } = -1;
        public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public List<PersonFamily> Families { get; set; }
        public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    } // class People

    public class Note
    {
        public int NoteID { get; set; }

        public int CreatedByID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
        public Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public int LastEditByID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LastEditByID")]
        public Person LastEditBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; set; }
        public string NoteText { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonFamily
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int FamilyID { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public Family Family { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is (and this is what makes impossible to EF to automatically determine the relationships) what is the relation between `Person.Notes` and `Note.CreatedBy` / `Note.LastEditBy` - none probably? You've said there is 0:M relationship between `Person` and `Note`, but note that there are potentially 3 one-to-many relationships there - notes associated with person, notes created by person and notes edited by person, which potentially leads to 3 FKs to Person in Note.

Also note that none of the navigation properties is required, but when present they must be paired.

Assuming you want 3 relationships, i.e. there is no relation between `Note.CreatedBy` /  `Note.LastEditBy` and `Person.Notes`, you need to tell EF that `Note.CreatedBy` and `Note.LastEditBy` do not have corresponding (a.k.a. inverse) navigation property in `Person`. This is not possible with data annotations. The only available data annotation for that purpose `[InverseProperty(...)]` does not accept empty/null string name, hence cannot be used for what is needed here.

Also there is another problem here which you will encounter after resolving the current, which also cannot be resolved with data annotations. Since you have multiple required (thus cascade delete by default) relationships from `Person` to `Note`, it creates the famous "cycles or multiple cascade paths" problem with SqlServer, and requires turning off at least one of the cascade delete.

With that being said, the model in question needs the following minimal fluent configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
    .HasOne(e => e.CreatedBy)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
    .HasOne(e => e.LastEditBy)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

The essential for the original issue are the `HasOne` / `WithMany` pairs. Once you do that, EF Core will automatically map the unmapped `Person.Notes` collection to a third optional relationship with no inverse navigation property and shadow FP property (and column) called "PersonId", i.e. the equivalent of

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Notes)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("PersonId");
```

Regarding the second issue with multiple cascade paths, instead of `Restrict` you can use any non cascading option or the newer `ClientCascade`. And it could be for just one of the relationships, as soon as it breaks the "cascade path" (apparently you can't break the cycle because it is demanded by the model).